# Enabling remote access in MS SQL Server 2012 Express

Tags: sql-server, remote-access

I'm trying to enable remote access in my install of MS SQL Server 2012 Express edition.

I found [this](http://blog.citrix24.com/configure-sql-express-to-accept-remote-connections/) and tried to follow this guide. Unfortunately the part "Configure SQL express server to listen on static port." failed. Brought up "Configuration Manager", selected "SQL Server Services", but saw the error "Remote procedure call failed".

Is there an easy way to fix this? Am I missing something? I looked thru the download page and didn't see any specific package that is required to et to make it work for the remote connection.

Could someone please help?

Answer (score 0):

You need to do a few things for SQL Express:

1) Enable TCP protocols.

2) Start the SQL browser server.

3) Set the ports to static for the sake of a local Firewall, otherwise a named SQL instance will use dynamic ports. Default port is 1433.

1 & 2 can be done in SQL Server Configuration Manager which will have been installed with the other applications.

[image]

Comment: thank you for the response. I will check it when I come back home and report back.

Comment: @Igor I should of also said that if you do have a local firewall you'll need to open a port for SQL Server connections.

Comment: this is given. ;-)

Comment: What version of MS SQL Server Configuration Manager do you have? Problem is on this laptop I have both 2008 and 2012. So, when I start it it shows the version as 2007.0100.1600.022. I should probably un-install 2008 version, but don't want to yet. So is there a way to make sure that this settings is applied to the proper version?

Comment: or is it just a generic setting for any SQL Server instance on the machine?